# Python- How To Remove Elements From a List Containing a Specific Word

Tags: python, list, arraylist

I want to remove elements from a list containing a keyword.

For example-

```
list1= [ 'one', 'one-test', 'two', 'two-test', 'three', 'three-test']
```

I want to remove all elements in this list that contain "-test".

So the final output should be -->

```
list1= ["one", "two", "three"] #because if it contained '-test' we just deleted the element as a whole
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using list comprehension we can easily accomplish this goal. Also using `in` we can check if a key word is in any elements in the given list.

```
list1= [ 'one', 'one-test', 'two', 'two-test', 'three', 'three-test']
newList = [elements for elements in list1 if '-test' not in elements]
```

**output**

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `list comprehension` and check if the element of the list contains `-test` during iteration.

```
remove = '-test'
list1= [ 'one', 'one-test', 'two', 'two-test', 'three', 'three-test']
[x for x in list1 if remove not in x]
#['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get this done is

```
list1= [ 'one', 'one-test', 'two', 'two-test', 'three', 'three-test']

for l in list1:
    if '-test' in l:
        list1.remove(l)
list1
```

Can also be done through list comprehenstion

Answer (score 1):

```
res = []
for item in list1:
     if len(item.split("-")) <=1:
          res.append(item)
# res = ['one','two','three']
```

You can use a new array and split the given array. Append the values that satisfy the condition.